# ios swift - table view with multiple data sources/nibs

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a table view that loads its data from two different data sources and chooses a specific nib depending on which one it is. How can I create a feed that mixes elements from two arrays of objects?

I was thinking about creating an array of objects with the objects being sorted by date. Then, I would check what the type of each object is at my cellforrowatindexpath method and use the nib that corresponds.

Is this the most efficient way of doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Creating a single array of objects and dealing with them correctly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a good approach.

You should register each of your nibs with the table view, probably in `viewDidLoad` using `registerNibForCellReuseIdentifier`. Make sure you use a different `reuseIdentifier` for each, then dequeue the correct type in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, once you've determined which type of cell it should be.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "fooCell", bundle: .mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "fooCellIdentifier");
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "barCell", bundle: .mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "barCellIdentifier");
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell?
    if (indexPathIsFooCell(indexPath)) {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("fooCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("barCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

    //customise the cell

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Josh, thanks so much man. I should dequeue the cell that I'm about to display as well as call the load nib with the appropriate one correct? I'm a bit confused with the dequeue vs the load in the way you explained it. Thank you for your help man

Answer (score 2):

**Here is Another Solution which Might help You**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("relatedTableViewCell") as? relatedTableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        let nib:Array = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("relatedTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)
        cell = nib[0] as? relatedTableViewCell
    }
    let info = relatedQuizArr.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as!  relatedInfo
   cell?.relatedImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: info.rqImage!))
   cell?.relatedLabel.text = (String: info.rqName!)
        cell?.rQuizView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1)
        cell?.rQuizView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
    return cell!
    } else {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("relatedTableViewCell") as? relatedTableViewCell
        if cell == nil {
            let nib:Array = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("relatedTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)
            cell = nib[0] as? relatedTableViewCell
        }
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(22, 10, 200, 40))
            label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(25)
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.text = "Featured Quiz"
            cell!.addSubview(label)
        }
        else {
        }
        let info = featuredQuizArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as!  relatedInfo
        cell?.relatedImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: info.featuredqImage!))
        cell?.relatedLabel.text = (String: info.featuredqName!)
        cell?.rQuizView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1)
        cell?.rQuizView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
        return cell!
    }
```

Hope It will help.

Comment: Could you explain a little more how your code solves the issue?

Comment: my code will load Diffrent XIB file on diff cells and on that row and cell you  can return your array object  to display according to your Need you can customise your XIb File

Comment: in my case i have 2 Section and no of cell in sec tion will be the value array will return  in noofrowsinSection .