# ios swift - load multiple data source in one tableview synchronously

Tags: swift, uitableview, datasource

i want a make a feed reader...i want load politics news from multiple data dource in one tableview synchronously.
what do i do?
i went to this link: [table view with multiple data sources/nibs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960403/ios-swift-table-view-with-multiple-data-sources-nibs)

but this solution is not synchronously
So basically what should be the approach when we have multiple data source but single instance of table view to show the data?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to create a backend service where the news are merged into one list. This allows you to easily edit the algorithm without the user having to update the app. And your backend also only have to crawl the websites once instead of every client having to do it every time a user wants to see the news.

When you fetch data from that service it will come in one list, and you already know how to do that :)

Comment: i don't use backend or json or xml

Comment: just i want put some of rss link into single array... i don't know how ...i want display some of rss link in single tableview

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be synchronously, because you wait for the rss response.
You better show a spinner and reload the tableview data once you collect all the responses.